# Problem with python web-scraping when reading a URL using "get" function

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have trouble using the "get" function to read the URL taken from cell A1 in the excel file "tennis3.xlsx". I have tried different solutions and I have no idea how to get it to read it and use it to get a webpage response. The problem probably starts at at 'sheet["A1"].value'.

I have applied this program through visual studio, with it using the chrome browser. The URL thats in cell A1 is https://www.betexplorer.com/tennis/atp-singles/paris/evans-daniel-nakashima-brandon/WAqNf5ao/.

edit: the actual issue I had with this was that I forgot to include the save function.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook(filename="tennis3.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.active
urlcell = sheet["A1"].value

response = requests.get(urlcell)
webpage = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

sheet["B1"] = soup.select('h1 a')[0].text.replace(' ','_')
```

Comment: What happens when you run this?  Have you printed `urlcell` to see what you get?  Is it a simple string?  Have you printed `webpage` to see what it sent back?

Comment: I tried your code and I got everything that it is supposed to be got. As @TimRoberts says: Can you share the outputs of your vars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the changes you made:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import load_workbook

filename = r"tennis3.xlsx"

workbook = load_workbook(filename=filename)
sheet= workbook['Sheet1']
urlcell = sheet["A1"].value
print(urlcell)

response = requests.get(urlcell)
webpage = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

sheet["B1"] = soup.select('h1 a')[0].text.replace(' ','_')
workbook.save(filename=filename)
```

Comment: thankyou, i've forgotten to add in a save function